Sharing a retrieved Instance with Function
Developing Android Kotlin personal app. Apparently my approach to give visibility to an instance of GMSBarcodeScanner in a Function called by a Button is incorrect. scannerInstance shows as "not used". What have I missed?
            Barcode.FORMAT_QR_CODE,
            Barcode.FORMAT_DATA_MATRIX
        )
        .build()

    val scannerInstance = GmsBarcodeScanning.getClient(this, options)
}
    fun clickToScan(view: View,scannerInstance: GmsBarcodeScanner) {
        // This function is triggered by Scan button
        scannerInstance.startScan()
            .addOnSuccessListener { barcode ->
                // Task completed successfully
                val result = barcode.rawValue
                return@addOnSuccessListener Toast.makeText(this, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show()

    

    


some parts of code are missing?

As is noted in a comment, your question currently is missing some code.
That said, it feels like the val scannerInstance line is inside of some function other than clickToScan(). That scannerInstance variable will go out of scope as soon as that function ends, and so it is unused.
